Getting into a 2008 Passat with a dead battery when the extra fob key isn't working
I have a 2008 Passat, in which I've unfortunately let the battery die. The key won't work but the batteries are fine. The actual physical plastic key which you get from the key fob for some reason doesn't open the car. How can I get into the car? I've tried a coat hanger, but the door handle is a nightmare to get hold of. I'm at a loss.

did you try the tailgate?

How could I open that as its locked

@Quirky: In many cars there is a hidden keyhole to release the tailgate if your car has lost power, but it seems to be internal in the 2008 Passat. I'm confused by you saying you have a plastic key, in Europe the 2008 Passat key has an integrated metal key. What does your key look like?

As an aside, my daughter had a Honda Fit which the driver's side had been damaged at some point where the door was replaced with a used door, but the lock wasn't changed out. It had power door latches with no other way to get into the car. After a couple of times breaking into the thing when the battery ran down, I drilled some holes in the wheel tub liner, put some electrical posts through the hole, then ran wires to the posts from the battery. Next time it happened, I just had to attach a 12v source to the posts and I could then unlock the car. PITB.

The key mechanism could be stuck from disuse. Perhaps some penetrating oil (PB blaster, etc.) where you would insert the key, then keep working the key gently but persistently until it gives.
If that key works to get into the trunk and you have a power port back there as most VWs do, make an adapter to fit the port and connect a jump start battery to backfeed the electrical system using + to the center pin, (-) to shell. Wait a few minutes, then hit the key fob and the door should open.
If you can jack up the car and support it safely and can get to the starter, connect a + jumper cable to the big fat starter terminal that has the big fat wire. The other end of the fat starter wire goes to + on the dead battery. Connect the (-) jumper cable to a good ground and both free ends of the jumper cables to another car battery or a booster. Use the key fob remote to unlock.
If you can get to the hood release lever with a coat hanger more readily than the door handle, pop the hood and charge the battery.

Thanks very much I'll give these a bash

Some hood release mechanisms may be more difficult to access under the front area but always worth a try if you understand hood release systems. Worse case is calling a locksmith to unlock doors. They may use an inflatable wedge, inserted between the top of a side window and window frame or door frame to force an opening enough to insert their tool to reach the unlock tab. These tools are available online too. Search youtube videos on how locksmiths unlock vehicles.
